# how to store data fetch from retrofit to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit, sql-insert

I have retrieve data from **Server** using Retrofit
and now I am trying to store with sqlite database.
But program not run get error in **BaseApter class and MainFragment**

**My Model Class Post**

in that class I set getter and setter

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("age")
    @Expose
    private String age;

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;

    @SerializedName("mob")
    @Expose
    private String mob;
```

My interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("fetch.php")
    Call<List<Post>> getContacts();

}
```

Retrofit Client

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Database class where I want to store the data

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ApointmentDb.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ApointList";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_AGE = "age";
    public static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
    public static final String TAG_MOB = "mob";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "" +
                "("
                + TAG_ID + " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                + TAG_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + TAG_AGE + " TEXT,"
                + TAG_CITY + " TEXT, "
                + TAG_MOB + " TEXT)";


        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);


    }

    public void addData(Post post) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TAG_ID, post.getId());
        contentValues.put(TAG_NAME, post.getName());
        contentValues.put(TAG_AGE, post.getName());
        contentValues.put(TAG_CITY, post.getName());
        contentValues.put(TAG_MOB, post.getName());


        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
```

and Adapter class

```
public class ApointmentAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {


    Context mContext;
    private List<Post> mContact;

    public ApointmentAdapter(List<Post> mContact, Context mContext) {
        this.mContact = mContact;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvId;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvAge;
        public TextView tvCity;
        public TextView tvMob;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mContact.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mContact.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public void addPost(Post post) {
        mContact.add(post);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_item_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvId  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_id);
            holder.tvName  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_name);
            holder.tvAge  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_age);
            holder.tvCity  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_city);
            holder.tvMob = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_mob);

            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        // now set your text view here like

       holder.tvId.setText(String.valueOf(mContact.get(position).getId()));
        holder.tvName.setText(mContact.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvAge.setText(mContact.get(position).getAge());
        holder.tvCity.setText(mContact.get(position).getCity());
        holder.tvMob.setText(mContact.get(position).getMob());

        // return your view
        return vi;


    }
}
```

And Last MainFragment Class

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Post> {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<Post> contacts;
    private ApointmentAdapter adapter;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private boolean firstTimeLoad = false;
    LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
    private DatabaseHelper myDb;

    private final String TAG = SaveToDatabase.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup v,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, v, false);
       LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ly_apointment_status);

        listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_apnt_status);

       ((ViewGroup)linearLayout.getParent()).removeView(linearLayout);

        adapter = new ApointmentAdapter(contacts,getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        apiInterface = APIClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<Post>> call = apiInterface.getContacts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

               if (response.isSuccessful()){
                  List<Post> contacts = response.body();

                     for (int i=0; i < contacts.size(); i++){

                         Post post = contacts.get(i);

                         SaveToDatabase task = new SaveToDatabase();

                         task.execute(post);

                         adapter.addPost(post);

                     }
                }else {

               }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return linearLayout;
    }

    public class  SaveToDatabase extends AsyncTask<Post, Void , Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Post... params) {
            Post postt = params[0];
            try{
                myDb.addData(postt);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

the error in Adapter class in **getcount method**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mContact.size();
}
```

and in Main Class

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where did I do a mistake?

**Logcat**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.s2r1.appointment, PID: 6560
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.s2r1.appointment.ApointmentAdapter.getCount(ApointmentAdapter.java:42)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
                                                                            at com.example.s2r1.appointment.StatusFragment.onCreateView(StatusFragment.java:65)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5241)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: first you need to post the log of the error, but one thing I notice where do you initialize the contacts list before passing it to adapter?

Comment: yes first i have directly retch data to my listview but now i want to store it into db without adding into listview

Comment: You haven't initialized array list @AhmedBasyouny was right ... you are getting null pointer exception when you try to setAdapter

Comment: @SayedRizwanHashmi while getting context in fragment use getContex();   because getActivity sometimes return null

Comment: thanks @akshay_shahane